# JQuery-UI : How to define sortable td tags of a Table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using JQuery-UI's [Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to sort my table's **td** tags of each row as

```
$(".scheduler").children('tbody')
    .children('tr').sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

but I found additional column has appeared. Here is ***[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaa7sun8/3/)*** Link. Can anyone give me suggestion ?

***Additional question*** : Can I sort **td** tags of the whole table instead of each row ? *(currently I can sort only **td** tags of same rows. I would like to drag one **td** and replace with another **td** tag of different rows)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the additional column, it is rendered, because when you start dragging an item, jQuery UI sortable adds a placeholder element to the row.
You could workaround this behavior by using

```
helper: "clone"
```

The placeholder will still be added, but the original element to be dragged will get `display: none` and the helper will be positioned absolutely.
Maybe, instead of using table, you could use a list… https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Regarding sorting the whole table, there is no simple way I can imagine using jQuery UI sortable. The best behavior I achieved so far is initializing using

```
$(".scheduler").sortable({
    items: "td"
});
```

but it will just move table cells from one row to the other causing more and more columns to be added to the table.

Comment: If so, I think there has no easy way to sort items across multiple rows of a table. May be I should choose other HTML element  instead of using **Table**.

Comment: For some reason my edit, where I added an idea, was not included. The idea was, as you mentioned, to use e.g. a list that is formatted using CSS to display N items in a row… http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

Answer (score 0):

make you jquery code like this

```
$(".scheduler tr").sortable({
    revert: true
});
```

i tried this on jsfiddle and working for td sorting

Comment: No .. I didn't say I can't even sortable. The problem is that "..but I found additional column has appeared." and "...I would like to drag one td and replace with another td tag of different rows" . Thanks.